# Is burnt ceramic frying pan safe to use?

Tags: frying-pan, non-stick, ceramic

I've been using a Bergner ceramic frying pan for a month and it has been ok up until today when I decided to cook beef burgers on it. After I was finished the ceramic coating was pretty burnt out. I've follow a cleaning method I found online with boiling water and baking soda, which cleaned it a lot, but there are still burnt bits here and there that won't go away.

Is it still safe to use?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Is this burned bits on top of the underlying coating, or burning of the coating itself?

Comment: Another thing you can do to unstick burnt bits is 1/3 fill the pan with water, add some washing up liquid and heat gently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frying pain is still safe to use (unless the ceramic chipped or cracked badly as well). A bit of vinegar (white) and a soft scrubber may get the rest of those burnt bits out as well. Either way, though, as long as the ceramic is intact, you can still use the frying pan safely.